# What does $F[x]$ mean?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, field-theory

> Lemma: $F$ is a field only if $F\left [ x \right ]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain.

This is a theorem from Ring; divisibility of integral domain.

What does $F\left [ x \right ]$ mean?

Comment: $F[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ whose coefficients belong to $F$.

Comment: @StevenHarding is correct, but I'll tack on that $F$ is itself a ring (if that wasn't implied already).